# border-spacing without outer spacing

Tags: html, css

My bad, i have a div and a div-table:

```
<div style="padding: 20px; border: 1px solid red;">
  <div style="width: 100%; display: table; border-spacing: 20px;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 33%; border: 1px solid blue;">a</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 33%;">a</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 33%;">a</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The distance be blue square and the red square is `40px` instead of `20px`.

I can not set the table's border to zero-width because border is a outer-distance and spacing is (like padding) a inner-distance.

I Can not drop the `border-spacing` because by principle its the correct decision to use it.

Any idea how to get the distance to `20px` without changing the outer `div`'s padding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a negative margin of 20px, so change your HTML to:

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/86s46/)

```
<div style="padding: 20px; border: 1px solid red;">
    <div style="width: 100%; margin:-20px;display: table; border-spacing: 20px;">
        <div style="display: table-cell; width: 33%; border: 1px solid blue;">a</div>
        <div style="display: table-cell; width: 33%;">a</div>
        <div style="display: table-cell; width: 33%;">a</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

That said, I would also recommend you move your styles out of being inline, and also question what you are really trying to accomplish- as by doing this, you are implementing a style to override one already in place- suggesting you should simply remove the existing style (though I appreciate you have already noted you cant).

Comment: Too bad, i can accept this answer in 12 minutes. you have to wait.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want the border spacing (the space between the cells) to be 20 px for both Horizontal and vertical ?

Try this where horizontally the cells will have 20 px spacing , but vertically it will be 0px.

```
border-spacing:20px 0px;
```

Comment: -1 If i follow this, i have two distances, 20px and 40px. And if i have a second row, the rows have a distance of 0px.

Comment: Yes true. Then it should not be the option . As i see in your code , the outer Div container doesnt need padding . Is there any specific reason for adding this ?  Because the border-spacing as you see is already giving you the 20px spacing that you need.

Comment: To solve the padding of the outer div is a **rule**, the real problem is that `border-spacing` do not differenciate between <cell>-margin and <table>-padding. It is bad principle to break a rule to solve a missing-feature where it is missed. So i workaround where the feature is missing, not where the missing-feature is affected.